# Command only reads first line of text file

Tags: python

I have to make a program in which one of the functions is retrieval of usernames and results from  a text file. (All on the same line)
For some reason, when I run it, only the first line is printed out. Why is this ? Also, this only happens when I try to run the program at school (part of an assignment), it prints everything it needs to on my laptop at home. (Python versions are also the same)

Here is my code :

```
def results():
       username = input("Enter username :")
       for line in open("resultsfile.txt","r"):
             if username in line:
                  print (line)
             elif username not in line:
                   ("No such user")
```

Also, this is what the text file looks like (without bullet points) :

- tud16 CS Easy 2points
- ser23 CH Med 4points
- tud16 CS Hard 1points

Comment: Is `("No such user")` supposed to be `print("No such user")`?

Comment: Do you mean to do `print("No such user")` else you're just putting a string on a line there...

Comment: I forgot to add the print (wrote this from my phone) but even with that it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
def results():
    username = input("Enter username :")
    for line in open("resultsfile.txt","r"):
        if username in line:
            print (line)
        else:
            print("No such user")
results()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over a file but you are printing `No such user` **for every line that does not match the username**.

What you should do is evaluate **after the loop** if one of the lines in the file contained the username. To implement this you could introduce a boolean (`found`) indicating if a user has been found or not:

```
def results():
   found = False
   username = input("Enter username :")
   for line in open("resultsfile.txt","r"):
       if username in line:
           print (line)
           found = True
   if not found:
       print("No such user")
```